# Identify the reason why a user has access to a record

Tags: userrecordaccess, record-access-level

`UserRecordAccess` tells you which records user has access to. But it doesn't inform why a user has access to that record.

I'd understand that this can be complicated but this is one source of questions and we go chasing all the reasons why a user has access.

Is there a list of rules or steps one can follow to highlight reasons behind a record access?

Comment: Click the sharing button then click expand I think. Tells you why each person has access to a record

Comment: Hi datasert! I've flagged this question as a duplicate to an answer I posted some time ago that includes step-by-step instructions and screenshots. If that resolves your problem, please let us know, otherwise I can retract my duplicate vote. If your problem is not resolved, please **[edit]** your question to include any additional information, such as what you've tried, why the previous solution does not work, etc, anything that will help us help you.

Comment: Somehow that question didn't show up when searched. Will take a look and see if that answers. If, not will add additional info.

Comment: Went through that question. That seems to give information I'm looking for. Will explore that for additional objects. Btw is there an API that provides access to that list of reasons given a record id?